# How to correctly inject service in constructor ?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a simple *interface* and a simple console application.

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
    string Operation();
}
```

and one *service* which implements the above *interface*.

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    public string Operation()
    {
        return "operation";
    }
}
```

Now I declare an *unity container* in order to use **dependency injection pattern** and a class called `CustomerController`.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
CustomerController c = new CustomerController();
c.Operation();
```

I want to inject the service inside `CustomerController`.

```
public class CustomerController
{
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public CustomerController()
    {

    }
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    public void Operation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_customerService.Operation());
    }
}
```

I know that for `Web API` and `MVC` application it's used a `DependencyResolver`.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

But how to *inject* `service` correctly in a simple console app ?

Comment: register the `CustomerController` with the container as well. the container will inject the dependency when resolving the controller

Comment: With Core 2, everything is a console app, including Web API and Web App. The services are automatically injected from the constructor's parameters. You don't need the empty default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the `CustomerController` with the container as well.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {

    var container = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>()
        .RegisterType<CustomerController>();

    CustomerController c = container.Resolve<CustomerController>();
    c.Operation();

    //...
}
```

The `container` will inject the dependency when resolving the controller

There is actually no longer a need for the default constructor and `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute if the dependency is only going to be used via the other constructor

```
public class CustomerController {
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService) {
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    public void Operation() {
        Console.WriteLine(_customerService.Operation());
    }
}
```